# Maintaining different instances of source code using TFS

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

My .net application exist in TFS. I made some changes , checkedin the same and deployed it . Now I got a new requirement . I want to keep the source code which has the previous changes untouched . Without creating another branch and maintaining the copy of the source code , Is it possible to checkin the new changes and also maintain the previous changes ?

Comment: The changes are maintained in TFS history, so you can always go back and view them at a later date.

Comment: @simon bosley , I am aware about history .But is there any possibility to save the new changes in a separate k instances/version  of source code .Does TFS provide functionality for it ?

Comment: Instances/version of source code usually go into different branches. @Balakumar what is putting you off creating a new branch for the version of code you'd like to remain 'untouched'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the closest that you can get to this is using TFS labels to identify different versions of the code.  It is, however, what branches are for, so I would definitely consider making a branch.